# MS Access 2010 - Send an automated email after form has been submitted

Tags: email, ms-access

I've been looking at trying to get my Access database to automatically send an email to notify me of an addition once a user has entered a new record through a form. I've tried using:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
oMail.Body = "Body of the email"
oMail.Subject = "Test Subject"
oMail.To = "Someone@somewhere.com"
oMail.Send
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

But it just gives me the error: Compile error: User-defined type not defined.

Comment: It doesn't "just" give you the error - it highlights the line with the error. Which is it?

Comment: This line: `Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()`

Comment: That's when you try to run it (the Sub fails). Stop the execution, and do Debug -> Compile. This shows where the compile error is.

Comment: I've stopped the execution now and it has highlight `oMail.Send` but when I try to select the Compile option from Debug, it is greyed out.

Comment: You must first "Reset" the execution with the blue square "Stop" button in the toolbar. If it's still disabled then, make a minor change (append a space to one line), but that shouldn't be the case as long as there is a compile error.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it the option is still greyed out. I tried typing in an error on purpose and that is picked up, but nothing else.

Comment: Weird. Well -- If you have set a reference to the Outlook object model, and it doesn't complain about `Outlook.Application`, then try `Outlook.MailItem` instead of `MailItem`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like that either unfortunately!

Comment: Please add screenshots (just the imgur links) of Tools-References and of the error message to your question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WQuQyuk

Comment: The error message too, please. But before you do that: Put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of the module (and all other modules).  
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. -- Then run Debug/Compile again.

Comment: The only error I get is the run-time '287' error that I posted a picture on in the same link. I have also made the changes you suggested and it doesn't seem to have changed much. And the option to compile the database is still greyed out.